# Определения создания файла

Tags: c, файлы, bash

У меня в задаче по С(си)
Задание: "Определить, будет ли создаваться файл, указанный в командной строке, при
программном обращении к нему. Вывести результат проверки на экран."
Я сделал это таким способом:

```
#include  <io.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

void main( void )
{
    FILE *file = "index.txt";
   if( (_access( file, 0 )) != -1 )
   {
      printf( "File %s.C sushestvyet \n", file );

      if( (_access( file, 2 )) != -1 )
         printf( "File %s has write permission\n", file );
   } else {
             printf( "File ne sushestvyet\n" );

   }
}
```

Так вот. Идет проверка файла, если его не существует, то может создаваться. Если существует - не может.  Но мне говорят, мол неправильно сделано и нужно сделать через `"fcntl, create"`. Подскажите пожалуйста, то не понимаю, чем это не подходит.

P.S знаю что тут не в командной строке (не соответствует 1 пункту), это позже доделаю

Comment: Вы уверены насчет "fcnte"? На закралась ли опечатка в названии?

Comment: "fcntl" Исправил. Спасибо

Comment: *если его не существует, то может создаваться. Если существует - не может.* Ха! а если нет прав на создание файла в этом каталоге? А если файл есть, но нет права увидеть его наличие? А если файла нет, но есть каталог с таким именем?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно Вам не зачли решение по той причине, что если файл не существует, то это не гарантирует что у Вас имеются права на запись в указанную директорию. Но советую уточнить требования к заданию. В любом случае, надеюсь данный листинг с минимальным примером использования fcntl и creat будет полезен:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int fd;
  char fn[] = "index.txt";
  if ( ( fd = creat( fn, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR ) ) < 0 )

    printf( "File cannot be created" );
  }
  else {

    print( "File can be created" );
  }
  return fd;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только библиотеки не все добавили, но в целом хорошо

Comment: Не подошло, надо было через fcntl